# shell script: how to compare process running time against a theshold?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, freebsd

Bash script should check if a certain process is running more than a certain number of minutes, and kill it if does.

I can get the running time by something like

```
ps -aux | grep ProgramName | grep -v grep | awk '{print $10}'
```

That gives `9:47.31` for instance. But where do I go further and check if that is greater than, say 10 minutes threshold?

Comment: Box is FreeBSD 6.2, shared hosting, if that makes sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the awk 1 liner you'll need for your use case:

```
ps -o etime -C ProgramName | awk -v MAX=600 '{split($0, a, ":"); if (length(a)==2) sec=a[1]*60+a[2]; else if (length(a)==3) sec=a[1]*3600+a[2]*60+a[3]; if (sec>MAX) print "Elapsed"; else print "Not Elapsed"}'
```

Also note that `ps -o etime -C ProgramName` gives you the time since ProgramName has been running so you don't need to use your overly complicated command to get this time.

**IMPORTANT:** Also remember that for the processes that have been running for more than a day you will get output of `ps` command as something like `1-21:48:48`. I don't have this case covered in my awk command but you can use the same `awk's split` command as I have shown above.

**UPDATE:** As per the comment below, use this version for FreeBSD or any other flavor of Unix (eg: Mac) where `-C ProgramName` option is not available.

```
ps -o etime=,command= | awk -v MAX=600 '/ProgramName/ && !/awk/ {split($1, a, ":"); if (length(a)==2) sec=a[1]*60+a[2]; else if (length(a)==3) sec=a[1]*3600+a[2]*60+a[3]; if (sec>MAX) print "Elapsed"; else print "Not Elapsed"}'
```

Comment: @anubhava -C switch on the FreeBSD 6.2 does something else, so perhaps those ugly greps are still needed.

Comment: Please check my answer in **Update** section above for FreeBSD platforms.

Comment: I only changed ps options in update to -o etime -o command — and it works now! Thank you anubhava!

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out. Difference between `ps -o etime -o command` and `ps -o etime= -o command=` is one extra line of headers in former.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible way:

```
for time in `ps auxwww  | awk '{print $10}'`; 
do  
SEC=`echo $time | cut -d":" -f2`; 
MIN=`echo $time | cut -d":" -f1`; 
TOTALTIMEINSEC=`echo $SEC+$MIN*60 | bc`; 
echo "the time in sec is:" $TOTALTIMEINSEC; done
```

BTW, you don't need to gerp -v grep, you can do:

```
grep [P]rogramName
```

That said, I'd love to see other solution, because I feel I'm recycling this methods...

Answer (score 1):

First, you can avoid the unnecessary grep -v grep and awk dance with the following instead:

```
$ ps -o time `pidof ProgramName`
```

On my linux machine this seems to give the time in the format HH:MM:SS.

Taking into consideration that `pidof ProgName` might give more than one value you might handle that with `tail -n +2|head -1` or something like that.

Now to get the duration you can convert the time into seconds:

```
$ seconds=$(printf "%d * 3600 + %d * 60 + %d\n" $(ps -o time $(pidof ProgramName)|tail -n +2|head -1|sed -e 's/:/ /g')|bc)
```

Note that the time given by `ps -o time` might be in this format too: `D-HH:MM:SS` where D is the number of days.

Comment: The server is on FreeBSD shared hosting. 'pidof' command is not available there.

Comment: In that case you want to replace ``pidof`` with ``pgrep``

Answer (score 1):

This will work for cases where your program has run less than a day

```
THRESH=360
ps auxwww | grep [P]rocessname | awk '{print $10}' | sed -e 's/:/ /; s/\.[0-9]*$//' | while read m s; do 
  let total=${m}*60+${s}
  if [ $total -gt $THRESH ]; then 
    echo "${total} seconds total is over threshold of ${THRESH} seconds"
  fi
done
```

If you want higher thresholds, you'll want to put some more logic around the extraction of process time, but at that point I'd put things into a perl/ruby script and get the information via `` `ps auxww ``w`

Comment: It doesn't like the floating point nature of seconds part: 2*60+43.97: syntax error in expression (error token is ".97")

Comment: You are correct.  I added another bit in the sed logic there to strip off the floating point part from the seconds if it exists.